# unique compound text indexes on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I've created an index on two fields `f1, f2` with `db.test.createIndex({"f1":"text","f2":"text"},{unique:true})`

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "unique" : true,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "f1_text_f2_text",
    "ns" : "test.test",
    "weights" : {
        "f1" : 1,
        "f2" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}
```

When I insert the two documents

```
db.test.insert({f1:"hello",f2:"there"})
db.test.insert({f1:"hello",f2:"there2"})
```

I get a duplicate key error

```
"E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: f1_text_f2_text dup key: { : \"hello\", : 1.1 }"
```

however `db.test.insert({f1:"hello2",f2:"there"})` works.

Are compound text indexes not supposed to work like regular compound indexes?

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure that you want a unique **text** index?

If you create a standard compound index:

```
db.test.createIndex({"f1": 1, "f2": 1}, {unique: true})
```

Then the following inserts will all be successful:

```
db.test.insert({f1:"hello",f2:"there"})
db.test.insert({f1:"hello",f2:"there1"})
db.test.insert({f1:"hello",f2:"there2"})
```

And this insert will then fail with `E11000 duplicate key error collection`:

```
db.test.insert({f1:"hello",f2:"there"})
```

You don't have to create a text index in order to index string fields. A [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) has a very specific role in supporting text searches but not all string searches require a text index. So, if you must ...

- Facilitate 'quick' text matches covering both `f1` and `f2`
- Enforce uniqueness across `f1` and `f2`

... then I suspect you will need to create two indexes:

- `db.test.createIndex({"f1":"text", "f2":"text"})`
- `db.test.createIndex({"f1": 1, "f2": 1}, {unique: true})`

Comment: I don't need the text index, the standard one works fine for my use case, but I started out using the text index (since I read some stackoverflow discussion instead of the documentation) and I just wanted to know why it doesn't respect the expected behaviour of a compound index. The official doc mentions compound indexes on the text index page and nowhere does it state that one should not expect the same behaviour as a standard compound index (with just the sort directions provided).

Comment: Stumbled upon the same issue yesterday. Fixed it by switching one of the two fields to ```ASCENDING``` instead of ```TEXT```. Still unable to understand why it behaves in such a manner when both fields have ```TEXT``` indexes?